# How to add simulator iPhone XS in Xcode 9.2 also iPhone XS max

Tags: xcode, macos, operating-system, ios11, xcode9.2

I need to build my app on an XS device. I am using Xcode 9.2.

How can I add the XS modal in my Xcode externally?

In my simulator I have up to iPhone X.

```
My machine Version:

OS X version: 10.12.6 (16G29)
Xcode version: 9.2
```

Comment: Do you have xcode 10 Right now? If you have then you can copy simulators from Xcode 10's package content and paste it in to xcode 9.2's Package content

Comment: I have Xcode 9.2 only

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Simple solution:**

1. Open Xcode.
2. Select the "Window" menu.
3. Select "Devices and Simulators".
4. Select Simulators tab.
5. Click on the "+" icon at the left bottom.
6. Choose the desired device & preferred iOS.
7. Click "Create".
8. Enjoy :).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 22):

For those here with the same problem but for **Xcode 10.x** and need **iOS 13 simulators** (iPhone 11, for instance) do the following:

1. Install and open Xcode 11
2. Go to `Xcode menu` > `Open Developer Tool` > `Simulator`
3. On the Simulator app, go to `Hardware menu` > `Device` > `iOS 13` to select and run your desired device
4. Now you can close **Xcode 11**, and open **Xcode 10.x**
5. You should see your i.e iPhone 11 simulator available in the **Device List** as the image:

[image]

Comment: So in the application list, we must need to keep both Xcode?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Or you could still migrate your project to be opened with latest Xcode version

Comment: I am using Xcode 10.1 (Simulator is also 10.1) but I have no iOS 13 in the list - I only have 11.4, 12.0, and -12.1.  Is there a way to add iOS 13 so that I can get the iPhone 11 simulator?

Comment: @Greg You have to install Xcode 11 too, then follow the steps above.

Comment: @Luiz - I was afraid of that - I believe am maxxed out at macOS 10.13.6 and therefore Xcode 10.1.

Answer (score 18):

In Xcode go to Window > Devices and Simulators
Here click on the simulators and then click on '+' to add a desired device.

Answer (score 7):

Update 2020

Open xcode simulator
File > Open device > select your desired device.

Answer (score 1):

for that u need to upgrade your xcode version to xcode 10, thats not available for xcode 9.2

Answer (score 1):

For Simulator `iPhone Xs 13.3` is not available by default in simulators list, So we would have to create it.

Steps :-

•Xcode Menu -> •Open Developer Tool -> •Simulator ->• Hardware -> •Device -> •Manage Devices -> •Simulators -> •Left Column -> •Click on + to create your device -> •Add Simulator Name (possibly `iPhone Xs 13.3`)…Device type to be iPhone Xs  and OS Version `iOS 13.3` -> •Create

Your New Device will be available in the list of Devices.

Similarly we can create other devices too.

[xcode]

---

Comment: Hello priyalp, for better and faster answers you could format your question with markdow (see https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) and add tags (maybe Xcode)

Answer (score 0):

> iPhone XS simulator is available on XCode 10 and above.

We can’t able to create a iPhone XS simulator on below `XCode 10`
But we can add

> iOS 12.0 simulators in XCode 9.3